# UI-Grid does not auto resize

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ng-grid, ui-grid

I am trying to use ui-grid and need to refresh my grid on some dom manipulation.

When using ng-grid, i could do it by:

```
$scope.gridOptions.$gridServices.DomUtilityService.RebuildGrid(
    $scope.gridOptions.$gridScope, 
    $scope.gridOptions.ngGrid
);
```

With `ui-grid`, `$gridServices` is showing undefined, has something changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like ui-grid has changed to create a auto resize and refresh through a module, I could get it working following below link:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/master/misc/tutorial/213_auto_resizing.ngdoc